# Sharepoint 365 - How to provide access to a service account?

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, office365

my organisation has recently upgraded their Sharepoint to 365. Previous versions of Sharepoint had the facility to grant access to a service account (EMEA\xxx...), however it appears 365 can only grant access to users via an email address. Is this correct? If not, please can you let me know how I can provide access to the service account?

Thanks very much in advance for any help you can offer

Regards,

David

Answer (score 1):

I think you mix up a couple of things here. Office365 separates internal tenant's accounts or external accounts.

External accounts: 
External accounts get created when one invites an external user to a shared resource. An external can only be invited based on their e-mail address.
Read more: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-external-sharing-for-your-SharePoint-Online-environment-c8a462eb-0723-4b0b-8d0a-70feafe4be85

Internal accounts: in a cloud-only ootb setup, internal accounts only live in the Azure Active Directory assiociated with your Office365 tenant. You can extend the setup by using a synchronized or federated setup using a Directory Synchronization tool. 
Identities in Azure Active Directory are identified by either the User Principle Name (UPN) or the user's e-mail address. The classic DOMAIN\USER representation is not supported.

With both setups, accounts from your on-premise Active Directory get copied to your Azure Active Directory (AAD). In the synchronized setup the password gets (securily) copied, so that users can log in with their login and password they now from their on-premise experience.
In the federated setup a user gets redirected to an on-premise ADFS end-point for authentication. At this end-point one can still use the DOMAIN\USER format for authentication.

Read more:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Understanding-Office-365-identity-and-Azure-Active-Directory-06a189e7-5ec6-4af2-94bf-a22ea225a7a9

In short: you should sync your service accounts towards Office365 and start using their UPN or "virtual" e-mail address. After having synced your service accounts you then can perfectly assign global Office365 admin rights to the AAD identity if that is what you would like to get established.